# Finding out all unique names in a Excel column

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have 2 worksheets that stores information about a weeks transactions. One is this week and the other is last weeks for comparison purposes.
The layout is the same for both companies.
There will sometimes be companies that had transactions last week but have not made one this week.

The company names appear in one column but can appear multiple times.

When I use the Excel Auto filter function it shows just the unique entries in that column and I would like to replicate that in VBA code so that I can output each company name that appears in either sheet.

I am looking for something similar to [Excel - All unique words in a range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20007039/excel-all-unique-words-in-a-range)
But in that solution the entries in the cells themselves are split up and I want the cell put in as a whole and compared.

Would it be simple as removing the JOIN code and changing `varValues = Split(strAllValues, " ")` to have the `strAllValues` to be the sheet range?

Any questions feel free to ask.

Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep the JOIN, but instead of using a space (" ") for the join use a pipe "|" and then again use a pipe for the split function, that will give you an array of all your individual names

Comment: Thanks for this as it works fine but I have another quick question if you don't mind. The Join works fine but in the same sub routine I also want to do the same join but on a different worksheet. I have tried the code `strAllValuesCompare = Join(Application.Transpose(Sheets("Compare).Range("C2", Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))), "|")` but I get a error "Application defined or object defined error. Any help?

Comment: Spotted the problem and fixed it.