# Creating a unique list of words from the same column of multiple sheets and sorting it alphabetically into a dynamic named range

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a user form that has a combo box with a list of names in it for the user to choose from. The list needs to be dynamic since I want the user to be able to type a name into the combo box if it doesn't exist already, but there needs to be a list of already existing names too for them to choose from. I found a similar question asked several years ago on here: [Excel - All unique words in a range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20007039/excel-all-unique-words-in-a-range)

The problem here is that it only works for one sheet and I can't see how to pull from multiple sheets using this, or how to sort the names automatically into alphabetical order.

This is the sub I'm using to create the dynamic range as it is now, the links to the original creator are left in to give credit where credit is due.

```
Sub SupplierListDynamic()
'Source: https://powerspreadsheets.com/
'For further information: https://powerspreadsheets.com/vba-create-named-range/
'declare object variable to hold reference to worksheet containing cell range
Dim myWorksheet As Worksheet

'declare variables to hold row and column numbers that define named cell range (dynamic)
Dim myFirstRow As Long
Dim myLastRow As Long
Dim myFirstColumn As Long
Dim myNamedRangeDynamic As Range    'declare object variable to hold reference to cell range
Dim myRangeName As String   'declare variable to hold defined name


Set myWorksheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("List_Data")  'identify worksheet containing cell range
myFirstRow = 2  'identify first row and first column of cell range
myFirstColumn = 9
myRangeName = "SupplierList"    'specify defined name

With myWorksheet.Cells
    'find last row and last column of source data cell range
    myLastRow = .Find(What:="*", LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    'myLastColumn = .Find(What:="*", LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column

    'specify cell range
    Set myNamedRangeDynamic = .Range(.Cells(myFirstRow, myFirstColumn), .Cells(myLastRow, myFirstColumn))
End With

'create named range with workbook scope. Defined name is as specified.
'Cell range is as identified, with the last row and column being dynamically determined
ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=myRangeName, RefersTo:=myNamedRangeDynamic
End Sub
```

but it's not sorted since I'm using`{=INDEX(Sep[SUPPLIER],MATCH(0,COUNTIF($I$1:I1,Sep[SUPPLIER]),0))}` to pull the unique values from another sheet, when I sort them, they just go back to their original order because of how the formula works. I'd rather this all be done with VBA to keep it in the back ground but I need some help tying everything together.

Comment: Are you using the top answer to that question? What you probably have to do is loop through each sheet to copy the values into one list on your master sheet and then de-dupe that.

Comment: Yes, I was looking at the first answer using a Dictionary object as the solution since it seemed the simplest on that sheet. So I'll need to run that script for each sheet and have them output to a long master list on the List_Data sheet and sort it down from there?

Comment: Once you have a unique list of names in `List_Data` create a named range:  `=List_Data!$A$1:INDEX(List_Data!$A:$A,COUNTA(List_Data!$A:$A))` and use that name in the `RowSource` for the combo-box (`=NameList`).  Then you can use `MATCH` or `FIND` when a name is added to check if it exists and add it to the bottom if it doesn't - the named range will automatically extend to include it.

Comment: That's how I'd do it. You could also check out http://www.snb-vba.eu/VBA_Sortedlist_en.html though probably easier to just sort before adding to the dictionary.

Comment: Unfortunately the names are being pulled from a list of records that are in date order so they can't be put in name order or else it will cause the table to read incorrectly.

Comment: But you are creating a new list. Or if using the SortedList you are not doing anything on the sheet anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up getting this figured out. What I ended up doing was copying only the string value for the supplier names to the next column, then clearing the original column and pasting the string values back into it. Then I used the procedure above to dynamically create the named range, and used the below procedure to sort the range.

This let me add new suppliers to the list and update the list accordingly. The two supporting procedures I used are below. Hopefully this will help someone out in the future.

```vb
Public Sub AddnewSupplier(supplier As String)
    Dim newRng As Range, supplierListColumn As Integer

    supplierListColumn = 9

    Set newRng = SelectFirstBlankCell(supplierListColumn, "List_Data")

    newRng.Value = supplier

    Call SupplierListDynamic
    Call sortSupplierList

End Sub

Public Sub sortSupplierList()
    Range("SupplierList").Sort Key1:=Worksheets("List_Data").Range("I1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
End Sub
```